# Select strings whose words match more than once the elements in a given array

Tags: r, regex

I have the following array of character strings:

```
text = c("not just #solar #wind, #geothermal but also now ocean power from waves", 
"Therefore we do not celebrate together Thanksgiving", "We obviously don't and cannot")
```

I would like to obtain two arrays from `text`, i.e. `text1` and `text2`. The first should contain only the strings of `text` that match more than once the elements in `mydata`:

```
mydata = c("No", "Not", "Don't", "cannot", "do not")
```

E.g. `text1` should contain:

```
We obviously don't and cannot
```

Instead, `text2` should contain all the other strings. Then:

```
not just #solar #wind, #geothermal but also now ocean power from waves, 
Therefore we do not celebrate together Thanksgiving
```

I could use `grep` but:

```
grep(mydata,text)
```

returns:

```
integer(0)
Warning message:
 In grep(mydata, text) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: may try `mydata <- paste0(mydata,collapse="|")`

Comment: I'm very confused. first *"`text` should contain"* and then *"instead `text` should contain"*. Which is it?

Comment: @r2evans sorry, I edited the post

Comment: In your `text2`, you have `do not` which is in your `mydata` ... which is it?

Comment: Text1 should contain only the strings of text that match more than once the elements in mydata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You imply case-insensitive in your question.

```r
text = c("not just #solar #wind, #geothermal but also now ocean power from waves", 
"Therefore we do not celebrate together Thanksgiving", "We obviously don't and cannot")

mydata <- paste("\\b(", paste(c("No", "Not", "Don't", "cannot", "do not"), collapse = "|"), ")\\b")

lens <- lengths(regmatches(text, gregexpr(mydata, text, ignore.case = TRUE)))

text[lens > 1]
# [1] "We obviously don't and cannot"
text[lens <= 1]
# [1] "not just #solar #wind, #geothermal but also now ocean power from waves"
# [2] "Therefore we do not celebrate together Thanksgiving"
```

The difference between `gregexpr` (along with `regmatches`) and `gsub` or `grep` is that the former extracts the matches as individual strings, while the others just indicate the presence of any (without a count). To see what they're doing:

```r
gregexpr(mydata, text, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 3
# attr(,"index.type")
# [1] "chars"
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
# [[2]]
# [1] 14
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 7
# attr(,"index.type")
# [1] "chars"
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
# [[3]]
# [1] 14 24
# attr(,"match.length")
# [1] 5 6
# attr(,"index.type")
# [1] "chars"
# attr(,"useBytes")
# [1] TRUE
```

That's a little hard to digest. The main number (not in an attribute) indicates the position within the string that a pattern matches; notice that in `[[3]]`, there are two matches. The attributes define the match length.

We can extract the matches with `regmatches`:

```r
regmatches(text, gregexpr(mydata, text, ignore.case = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "not"
# [[2]]
# [1] "do not "
# [[3]]
# [1] "don't"  "cannot"
```

And from here, `lengths` gives us the relative length of each of these, representing the number of matches in each string of `text`.